# Google Geochart Without Geocoding

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

I can't find a clear answer for this one. I've read that there is no limit for Google Charts. However, I have read that there is a limit on using geocharts because of the usage of geocoding which falls under the Google Maps API. That said, under Google Geocharts Data policy, there is this:

> Locations are geocoded by Google Maps. Any data that does not require
>   geocoding is not sent to any server. Please see the Google Maps Terms
>   of Service for more information on their data policy.

Is there any way that I can be sure that I am not using geocoding when I set the locations.

My locations are sent to the Geochart API as latitude-longitude, ISO-3166-1 alpha-2, or ISO-3166-2.

I just want to be sure that I am not using geocoding because I could have 25,000+ calls a day and do not want to have an issue with the Google Maps API Limits.

Comment: Lat/Long coordinates should not require geocoding, but you can confirm by looking at the network tab in Chrome's developer console while the chart is drawing.  If there are any geocoding requests, they will show up in the network activity.

Comment: The only thing with geocode is this link http://www.gstatic.com/charts/regioncoder/0/geocodes/countries_en.js But from the looks of it, it is only getting the iso 3166 country name from the country code. No processing on their end such as with addresses.